# How to wait for FirebaseAuth to finish initializing?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Integrated Firebase Authentication to my app. Everything seems to be fine, until I noticed the issue wherein I open the app, it shows me the login screen, even though there is already a user signed in.

Exiting the app and launching it again solves the problem (app no longer asks the user to sign in again), though it provides the users a very bad experience.

I've read the docs, and apparently, calling `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` might return null if auth haven't finished initializing. I'm assuming that's the reason why the issue happens. So I wonder if there is a way to wait for FirebaseAuth to finish its initialization before I can call getCurrentUser()?

Comment: Can you have a runnable that lets you wait for a few seconds?

Comment: I already have one for the launch screen. It's set to wait for five seconds. I can no longer have the user wait for another second longer than that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the modern API, simply wait for auth state to change:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => init_your_app);
```

Comment: But can we be sure, that the user is in fact authenticated? As to my understanding a state change in auth could also be triggered by a sign out.

Comment: @KevinKreps yes you can be sure: on the callback , if the user object exists, it means it's authenticated, and undefined when not authenticated. It's mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 9):

You can create function which returns promise, and await where needed:

```
function getCurrentUser(auth) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        unsubscribe();
        resolve(user);
     }, reject);
  });
}
```

Check this - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/462

Answer (score 7):

For React users who are asking the same question :

[react-firebase-hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/auth) has a hook called `useAuthState` that can prove to be helpful for checking the state of firebase auth.
Following is a very common use-case I think.

```
import {useAuthState} from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import React from "react";

export default function AllowIfAuth() {
    const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
    if (loading) {
        return <div> Loading... </div>;
    } else if (user) {
        return <div> Some Content </div>;
    } else if (error) {
        return <div>There was an authentication error.</div>;
    } else {
        return <LoginPage/>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cannot believe that I have to do this (as there is no official API by Google). I have to use one additional boolean...

```js
let isAuthReady = false

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  store.commit('setUser', user)

  if (!isAuthReady) {
    isAuthReady = true
    init()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

now we have `Auth.authStateReady()` for JS

```
            auth.authStateReady()
                .then(() =>
                    onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
                       // logic...
                    })
                )
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth.md#authauthstateready

not sure about Java equivalent

Answer (score 0):

You need a listener that tell you when the authentication is done, this link might help you : [FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)

Comment: this and Doug's answer would work for the user but does not actually answer his question. His question was, _is there any means to promise/otherwise determine when firebase auth() has finished initializing?_

Comment: how do you know which of these cases is true when your calback is called? `This method gets invoked in the UI thread on changes in the authentication state:

    Right after the listener has been registered
    When a user is signed in`

Answer (score 0):

You can call [getCurrentUser()](http://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()) to know, if, at this very moment in time, it's known that a user is logged in.  If you need some bit of code to be triggered when the user logs in or out, you'll need to register a listener to be notified when there is a change.  There is a method [addAuthStateListener()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)) that will trigger on that change.  Be sure to read that javadoc to understand exactly the conditions when it will fire.  In side the [AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener) that you add, you will be able to call getCurrentUser() to know if the user is logged in.

Comment: this isn't guaranteed immediately after login. the auth object may not be finished initializing. further, you may get a non-null user object back, but all fields/properties on it are still null. the login method .onComplete() fires before the authStateListener has completed

Comment: @FirefighterBlu3 If you have a specific reproduction case for this, file a bug report.  There should be no inconsistencies.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson 
I've been into this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/462 thread almost since it started (few years ago).
Firebase auth API treats the auth state as 2 possible states: Logged in, Not logged in.
But it's not taking into consideration a "Doesn't now yet" state, that is real before Firebase Auth finished figuring out if user is indeed authenticated or not.
If you log in and refresh the page, for a few moments firebase won't know that you're logged in and getCurrentUser will be nul.

Comment: And according to docs authStateListener firesupt "Right after the listener has been registered", and at this point it's not finished yet on figuring out if user is indeed logged in or not.