# Firebase Auth not reading local token

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Auth and created a context provider to make the logged in user available to the app.

I am protecting certain routes in my app to only users that are logged in. If a user is not logged in (i.e. there is no User in the context provider) and they try access a protected route, they are redirected to the login page.

The problem I have is that a user can log in and go to a protected route, however, if they refresh the page, they are redirected to the login page. For some reason, the user is not loaded and I can see a call is made out to https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup.

I am using local persistence when I configure Firebase Auth, so I believe the reason for my problem is that Firebase Auth is not looking at local storage first, and instead, is always making a request to https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com.

Here is how I have my app...

First, I initialize my Firebase app:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "...",
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
setPersistence(getAuth(), browserLocalPersistence).then(() =>
  console.log("Set persistence: "  + Date.now())
);
export const firebaseAuth = getAuth();
```

Snippet of the context-based authentication provider using Firebase Auth:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(firebaseAuth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  const values = { user, login, signup, logout };
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={values}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

Make this provider available to the app:

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Create an `AuthRoute` to protect routes to only allow logged in users:

```
export const AuthRoute: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const location = useLocation();
  const { user } = useUserAuth();

  return user ? (
    <>{children}</>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/users/login" state={{ returnUrl: location }} />
  );
};
```

Finally, I wrap the protected routes with the `AuthRoute`:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/manage"
    element={
      <AuthRoute>
        <ProtectedLayout />
      </AuthRoute>
    }
  >
    //...
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

How can I get Firebase Auth to look in local storage for the user token first, instead of always making a request to the auth endpoint?

#### UPDATE

After further research, it turns out that even if the auth information is in local storage, Firebase Auth will still reach out to the server before considering the user logged in.

From [How to Store Credentials to Local Storage to Allow Firebase Auth to Sign-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925051/how-to-store-credentials-to-local-storage-to-allow-firebase-auth-to-sign-in)

> Firebase already stores the user credentials in local storage, and
> automatically restores them when you reload the page.
>
> Restoring them does require a check against the server though, so it
> happens asynchronously

So now my question is, how can I change the `AuthRoute` to:

- Return `<Navigate to />` if there is nothing in local storage
- If there is something in local storage, wait until `onAuthStateChanged` completes and return `<>{children}</>` or `<Navigate to />` depending on how the promise resolves.

Comment: Any questions, please comment so I can edit my answer, I wish you success on your journey :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How to solve

---

> Return `<Navigate to />` if there is nothing in local storage

You can verify with:

```
if(!localStorage.getItem(yourKey))
    return <Navigate to="your_path" />
```

> If there is something in local storage wait until onAuthStateChanged completes and return <>{children}</> or  depending on how the promise resolves.

[react-firebase-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-firebase-hooks) has a hook called useAuthState that can prove to be helpful for checking the state of firebase auth. Following is a very common use-case I think.  
Example:

```
import {useAuthState} from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import React from "react";

export default function AllowIfAuth() {
    const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
    if (loading) {
        return <div> Loading... </div>;
    } else if (user) {
        return <div> Some Content </div>;
    } else if (error) {
        return <div>There was an authentication error.</div>;
    } else {
        return <LoginPage/>;
    }
}
```

Reference: [How to wait for FirebaseAuth to finish initializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231344/how-to-wait-for-firebaseauth-to-finish-initializing)

#### Remarks

---

If this answer was not satisfactory, or confusing, or did not answer what was asked, please comment so I can edit it.

It's worth mentioning that I'm using google translator to answer, I apologize for any inconvenience